# Better way to bind an entire vector/list to every row of a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, vector, nested

I want to bind an entire vector to each row of a dataframe, then unnest so I can search some text for a keyword.

Basically I want to this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- tibble(text = c(
  "I really like apples, tomoatoes, and cucumbers",
  "I really like berries, chocolate, and apples",
  "I really like avocado, chocolate, and carrots"
  ))

keywords <- c("apple",
              "tomato",
              "cucumbe",
              "chocolate",
              "avocado")

df %>% 
  mutate(keyword = keywords)
```

But that results in this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `keyword`.
x Input `keyword` can't be recycled to size 6.
i Input `keyword` is `keywords`.
i Input `keyword` must be size 6 or 1, not 5.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

So I'm finding myself doing this intermediary step which seems unnecessary:

```
keywords_string <- str_c(keywords$keyword, collapse = ",")

df %>%
  mutate(keyword = keywords_string,
         keyword = str_split(keyword, ","))
```

Is there a way for me to do this without first making collapsing the vector to a string and then splitting the string? Thanks!

Comment: Wrap it with `list()`? `df %>% mutate(keyword = list(keywords))`.

Comment: Do you want to have the keywords shown as separate columns then? Or do you want to expand your data frame so that each original row is expanded as many times as matched in the keywords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping it in `list` is an easier way to get the output for the second code. But, if you're just going to `unnest` right after you could do it all in one step with `tidyr::expand_grid`

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  expand_grid(keyword = keywords)
#> # A tibble: 15 × 2
#>    text                                           keyword  
#>    <chr>                                          <chr>    
#>  1 I really like apples, tomoatoes, and cucumbers apple    
#>  2 I really like apples, tomoatoes, and cucumbers tomato   
#>  3 I really like apples, tomoatoes, and cucumbers cucumbe  
#>  4 I really like apples, tomoatoes, and cucumbers chocolate
#>  5 I really like apples, tomoatoes, and cucumbers avocado  
#>  6 I really like berries, chocolate, and apples   apple    
#>  7 I really like berries, chocolate, and apples   tomato   
#>  8 I really like berries, chocolate, and apples   cucumbe  
#>  9 I really like berries, chocolate, and apples   chocolate
#> 10 I really like berries, chocolate, and apples   avocado  
#> 11 I really like avocado, chocolate, and carrots  apple    
#> 12 I really like avocado, chocolate, and carrots  tomato   
#> 13 I really like avocado, chocolate, and carrots  cucumbe  
#> 14 I really like avocado, chocolate, and carrots  chocolate
#> 15 I really like avocado, chocolate, and carrots  avocado
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That's awesome.  I feel like tidyr/dplyr has a function for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case TO wants to have the keywords added as separate columns:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(keyword = list(keywords)) %>%
  unnest_wider(keyword) %>%
  rename_with(.cols = starts_with("..."), ~paste0("keyword_", 1:length(keywords)))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  text                                           keyword_1 keyword_2 keyword_3 keyword_4 keyword_5
  <chr>                                          <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1 I really like apples, tomoatoes, and cucumbers apple     tomato    cucumbe   chocolate avocado  
2 I really like berries, chocolate, and apples   apple     tomato    cucumbe   chocolate avocado  
3 I really like avocado, chocolate, and carrots  apple     tomato    cucumbe   chocolate avocado
```

Comment: rename_with, that's great

Answer (score 0):

An option is also with `crossing`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   crossing(keywords)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 15 x 2
   text                                           keywords 
   <chr>                                          <chr>    
 1 I really like apples, tomoatoes, and cucumbers apple    
 2 I really like apples, tomoatoes, and cucumbers avocado  
 3 I really like apples, tomoatoes, and cucumbers chocolate
 4 I really like apples, tomoatoes, and cucumbers cucumbe  
 5 I really like apples, tomoatoes, and cucumbers tomato   
 6 I really like avocado, chocolate, and carrots  apple    
 7 I really like avocado, chocolate, and carrots  avocado  
 8 I really like avocado, chocolate, and carrots  chocolate
 9 I really like avocado, chocolate, and carrots  cucumbe  
10 I really like avocado, chocolate, and carrots  tomato   
11 I really like berries, chocolate, and apples   apple    
12 I really like berries, chocolate, and apples   avocado  
13 I really like berries, chocolate, and apples   chocolate
14 I really like berries, chocolate, and apples   cucumbe  
15 I really like berries, chocolate, and apples   tomato
```

---

Regarding the OP's comment about the difference in `expand_grid` and `crossing`, the latter deduplicates if there duplicate elements

```
> expand_grid(v1 = rep(letters[1:2], each = 2), v2 = rep(letters[3:4], each = 2))
# A tibble: 16 x 2
   v1    v2   
   <chr> <chr>
 1 a     c    
 2 a     c    
 3 a     d    
 4 a     d    
 5 a     c    
 6 a     c    
 7 a     d    
 8 a     d    
 9 b     c    
10 b     c    
11 b     d    
12 b     d    
13 b     c    
14 b     c    
15 b     d    
16 b     d    
> crossing(v1 = rep(letters[1:2], each = 2), v2 = rep(letters[3:4], each = 2))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  v1    v2   
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     c    
2 a     d    
3 b     c    
4 b     d
```

Comment: Just read the docs on this and `expand_grid` . . . why use one or the other?

Comment: It is a function for a specific purpose ie. deduplicates

Comment: @BenG I updated with the difference